# Array as a parameter of a dialog function in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, function, parameters, dialog

```
#!/bin/bash

function dialog_menu()
{

    arr["$4"]="$(dialog --clear --backtitle "Archlinux Installer" --title "$1" --menu $2 10 60 5 $3 --output-fd 1)"

}

ARRAY[0]="\"sda\""
ARRAY[1]="\"The main disk\""

dialog_menu "Disk Selection" "Please, choose where to install Archlinux" "$(echo ${ARRAY[*]})" DISK_SELECTION

echo "${arr[DISK_SELECTION]}"
```

The challenge here is to get dialog --menu to read my array. But for some reason I can't find a way to make it work.

## EDIT 1 :

I tried changing the array to `array=('sda' 'super cool' 'sdb' 'less cool')` and substitution outside the function works with `"${array[@]}"` . But once it's in the function, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I suggest you to make the third argument (`$3`) to `dialog_menu` be `DISK_SELECTION`, then all arguments from `$4` up will be `ARRAY`'s content. So, `dialog_menu "Disk selection" "Please..." DISK_SELECTION "${ARRAY[@]}"`. I would also like to suggest you to lower-case your variable names (i.e. `array` instead of `ARRAY` or any other lower-cased name) as by a convention environment variables and internal shell variables are fully capitalized. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidently overriding environmental and internal variables.

Comment: [Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments) is a great source for you to further read and learn from :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(
    'sda' 
    'super cool' 
    'sdb' 
    'less cool'
    'sdc'
    'there is another ?'
)

function dialog_menu()
{

    arr["$1"]="$(dialog --clear \
            --backtitle "$2" \
            --title "$3" \
            --menu "$4" 10 60 3 \
            "${!5}" --output-fd 1)"

}

dialog_menu disk_selection "Menu" "Menu Test" "This is a test for Menu entry" array[@]
```

The trick was to use `${!5}` as variable of the `dialog_menu` function, then call the array normally with `array[@]`

N.B : modified the code a little to ensure better reading